# index out of range array swift

Tags: arrays, swift

i get error index out of range in array

here's my code

```
.response { request, response, _, error in
            self.localPath = destination(NSURL(string: "")!, response!)
            self.localPathArray.append(self.localPath!)
        }
        cell.progressDownload.hidden = false
        cell.progressLabel.hidden = false
    }

    if statusInstantiante == true {
        let mainStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc:RedirectMagazineViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NEXT") as! RedirectMagazineViewController

        vc.receiveData = self.localPathArray[indexPath.row] //Error
        vc.receiveTitle = titleMagazine[indexPath.item]

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("still downloading")
    }
}
```

I Download pdf file using alamofire download, and get the path (localPath) and append it to localPathArray. the build succeded and can download completely but if i want to view the pdf file it prints index out of range.

Comment: Well the problem, most probably, is with `indexPath.row`, I guess you set the wrong value for number of rows.

Comment: ah, yes i check it and after download the index path is not correct, but some of pdf file have the correct index path so it can view. is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your line into something like this:

```
if (self.localPathArray.count > indexPath.row) {
   //this condition ensures that your will not request an index that does not exist in the array
   vc.receiveData = self.localPathArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: appear new error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in `self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: receiveData))`

Comment: Ok so this was solved. And this what you last worte to comment is another problem, that is already for a new question.